# Flirtatious Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, puzzle, recreational-mathematics

Here's a possibly interesting prime puzzle. Call a prime $p$ flirtatious if the sum of its digits is also prime. Are there finitely many flirtatious primes, or infinitely many?

Comment: I'm interested in seeing whether or not it depends on the base. It's clearly infinite for unary. :P

Comment: Mersenne primes are flirtatious in binary.

Comment: Down-voted because answer can easily be found by calculating a few terms and searching OEIS.  See Gerry Myerson answer below.

Comment: @FredDanielKline: Not everyone knows about OEIS (yet). Asking a question like this one is a way to find out about it.

Comment: @FredDanielKline This is also a nice way for other members of the forum, such as myself, to come across an interesting problem they might otherwise not have heard about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are [tabulated](http://oeis.org/A046704) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. It appears to be known that there are infinitely many, and a [link](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Harman/harman2.pdf) is given to a recent paper of Harman. Some high-powered math is involved.